# Dokuwiki: Block certain sections from editing?

Tags: dokuwiki

I'm creating a DokuWiki and have a specific template for new pages. One section uses the include and data plugins, so they are for display of external data only. I don't want users being able to mess with this code, so it would be handy to block them from editing those particular sections. I couldn't figure out any particular strategy to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that in DokuWiki. DokuWiki's ACL system only works on the page level. Your only way to achieve something close to this is to work with the include plugin. Make your main page readonly, then include different pages for the different sections. Make the pages for the sections you want to have editable editable and the others read only. Then point your users to the individual pages for editing.